# MySQL use Filter Table on Array of other Table

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, mariadb

I have two tables: profile and hobbie

Each profile is abled to choose up to hobbie, what will be safed in profile.p_hobbies as array of id's (*e.g.: [1,5,7,8,9]*)

Now i want to get the names of a profile's hobbie.
I thougth it should be something link:

```
SELECT hobbie.h_name
FROM profile, hobbie
WHERE profile.p_id=37 AND hobbie.h_id IN profile.p_hobbies
```

The result is a **failure #1064**

*#1064 - Fehler in der SQL-Syntax. Bitte die korrekte Syntax im Handbuch nachschlagen bei 'profile.p_hobbies LIMIT 0, 25' in Zeile 3*

I already use the IN method in other SQL-Querys. I guess I can't use it if the Array I want to use is also data from the SQL Database?

Is there anything I can do without using multiple queries?

I'm using MariaDB-9

Comment: MySQL does not support arrays in a way PostgreSQL does. Second storing CSV as column value is not best idea.

Comment: what's the relationship between the tables? how are they linked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as an array type in MySQL. You have a problem with your data structure. You should have an *association*/*junction* table, with one row per user and hobby. Something like this:

```
create table profileHobbies (
    profileHobbieId int auto_increment primary key,
    profileId int,
    hobbieId int,
    foreign key (profileId) references profiles(profileId),
    foreign key (hobbieId) references hobbies(hobbieId)
);
```

Rows would looks like this:

```
profileHobbieId   profileId   HobbieId
       1              1           1
       2              1           3
       3              1           5
```

Then your query would look like:

```
SELECT h.h_name
FROM profileHobbies ph JOIN
     hobbie h
     ON ph.hobbie_id = h.hobbie_id
WHERE ph.profile_id = 37 ;
```

There are many reasons why you don't want to store a list of hobbies as a delimited string. Here are some:

- The ids are integers.  Data should be stored using the correct type and integers are not strings.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly declared.
- SQL has lousy string processing capabilities.
- The string functions needed to manage the list prevents the optimizer from using indexes.
- SQL has a really great data structure for storing lists. It is called a *table*, not a *string*.

Answer (score 1):

Your best choice is to *normalize* your data. Storing sets of numbers as comma-delimited lists is considered harmful in SQL. Why harmful?

- it doesn't scale up well because it can't use indexes to search
- updating the sets of numbers is hard;  consider the problem of removing `2` from `1,2,3,4`. That's a mess in SQL.

Some SQL variants have support for the updating function. But the scale-up problem is still there. (Don't be too offended at this advice: most of us have made this database-design mistake at one time  or another.)

You have a many-to-many relationship between profiles and hobbies.  Therefore you need a table, named `profile_hobbie` with two columns in it, `p_id` and `h_id`.
When a profile starts doing a hobby, you insert a row into `profile_hobbie` with the id of the profile and of the hobby.  If a profile stops doing a hobby, you delete that row.

Then your query would look like this:

```
  SELECT hobbie.h_name
    FROM profile
    JOIN profile_hobbie ON profile.p_id = profile_hobbie.p_id
    JOIN hobbie ON profile_hobbie.id = hobbie.h_id
   WHERE profile.p_id=37
```

This will yield a (possibly empty) list of hobbies for the chosen profile.

You could also try using [MySQL's FIND_IN_SET() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), but you may run into conversion trouble between integers and strings.

```
   SELECT hobbie.h_name
     FROM profile
     JOIN hobbie ON (FIND_IN_SET(hobbie.h_id, profile.p_hobbies) > 0)
```

But, Gordon is right. This uses a lousy string-processing hack.